# disable the click event of button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am new to iPhone development.

In my application,

i want to disable the click event of button when it pressed first time by the user. 
for that purpose
i tried

```
buttonname.Enable=FALSE;
```

But the image of button also goes washed like a disable.
i Want to show Image properly and button should be disabled, both at time.
what to do?
Please help me.
Thanks For Your Time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set `buttonname.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` This will disable the action of the buttonname but the `UIButton` will be shown. Only the clicked event will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code it may help you

```
[buttonName addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting its `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`.